# Find the date of the latest orders for a product and list all customers who have ordered that product on that date

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm query builder in Microsoft Visual Studio C# and this is the code I have so far, however I will like to display the customers details and date placed who have ordered a specific item latest.

Any help will be much appreciated as I am stuck in a rut. Thank You for your time.

```
SELECT Corder.Corder_No, Corder.Customer_No, Corder.Date_Placed, Customer.Name, 
       Product.Product_No, Product.Description
FROM  Corder 
      INNER JOIN Customer ON Corder.Customer_No = Customer.Custno 
      CROSS JOIN Product
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to suggest you anything without seeng your database schema because that schema is unclear just from looking to your query.

Comment: How can I show you the database schema Andy? Cheers.

Comment: Well, you can edit your question using appropriate link below the question tags. Describe tables and columns storing data concerned to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Corder-table has a reference to product_num you could try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    co.Corder_No, 
    co.Customer_No, 
    co.Date_Placed, 
    c.Name, 
    p.Product_No, 
    p.Description
FROM  Corder co 
INNER JOIN Customer c ON co.Customer_No = c.Custno                
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.Product_No = co.Product_No
WHERE co.Date_Placed = (
    SELECT MAX(Date_Placed) 
    FROM Corder co2 
    WHERE co2.Product_No=p.Product_No
)
```

Comment: Guessing and assuming is a bad approach to answer a question. Instead, get all the required information from OP first.

Comment: No joy mate. When i try to put MAX function in the date_placed column i get the error conversion failed when converting datetime from character string....

Comment: Well, as the comments says to your question, you must describe the database before anyone can help you